# Remove special characters from JSON data in React

Tags: json, reactjs, rest, api

I'm pulling a JSON through REST API using React, and then displaying the data however I'm getting some weird characters showing up in the text.

I'm using UTF-8 and React library 'html-react-parser' this has helped remove most of the characters but these ones are stubborn..

Example of the characters:

WeÃ¢ÂÂd

I have seen some posts that refer to the JSON data itself being encoded wrong, unfortunately I can edit this client side.

Any ideas on how to remove these?

Thanks!

Comment: Since you are not providing what a good character would be: `stringYouWantCleaned.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '')`

Comment: Thanks for that, problem is I'm not sure what the replacement should be.. I was hoping for a solution that would parse the JSON data but will give this a go!